# After my app scans the QR code nothing happens

Tags: java, android

I have followed a tutorial to integrate zxing into my application and that has worked great, the only problem now is that when I scan the qr code nothing launches, I am a complete newb and some input would be a great help.
My java is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


private Button scanBtn;
private TextView formatTxt, contentTxt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
    formatTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
    contentTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_content);
    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v){
    //respond to clicks
    if(v.getId()==R.id.scan_button){
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
        }
    }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
        contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
        }else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
    }

}
```

I would like to launch into the browser but I'm sure I'm missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually launch any of your results.  If you scanned text that turned out to be a website link you would need to launch an intent for the web browser to open.

In activity result after you read the results in you would do something like this:

```
Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(<INSERT URL>));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks I new I was missing something obvious, great help!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the string from the QR Code, you need to launch browser in following way:

```
String url = "Url String";
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse(url));
try {  
      // Start the activity  
      startActivity(myIntent);
      this.finish();
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {  
      // Raise on activity not found  
      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Browser not found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
    }
```

Hope this helps